# Context.SaveChanges() in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is an easy question and I want to confirm with you experts!

I am changing some values in two different tables in same database. Is it okay to just call SaveChanges one time to update all? Seems to work but I want to know if its okay or need to call context.SaveChanges after every update?

```
bool success = false;
TestSuiteDB context = new TestSuiteDB();

var workstyle1 = context.WorkStyle.Where(d => d.WorkStyleId==21 && d.MemberId==1).ToList();
foreach (var ws1 in workstyle1)
{
    ws1.ModuleId = flid1;
}

var workstyle2 = context.WorkStyle.Where(d => d.WorkStyleId == 22 && d.MemberId==1).ToList();
foreach (var ws2 in workstyle2)
{
    ws2.ModuleId = flid2;
}

var workstylemodules1 = context.WorkStyleModules.Where(d => d.WorkStyleModuleId == 2 && d.MemberId == 1).ToList();
foreach (var ws1 in workstylemodules1)
{
    ws1.ModuleId = flid1;
}

var workstylemodules2 = context.WorkStyleModules.Where(d => d.WorkStyleModuleId == 3 && d.MemberId == 1).ToList();
foreach (var ws2 in workstylemodules2)
{
    ws2.ModuleId = flid2;
}

if (context.SaveChanges() > 0)
{
    success = true;
}
```

Comment: LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `Context.SaveChanges();` **once** after all the updates and it will save all the changes done previously.

If you are expecting to change/insert a new object, and wants to modify the next objects based on the database's actual value, you may call `Context.SaveChanges()` so that the database gets updated.

Any changes/insertion to the entities are tracked in the context and once `SaveChanges` is called, it put the changes in the database as well.

Also keep this in mind:
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx):

> SaveChanges operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back
>   that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty
>   ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to call it once.you may also need a [transactional code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) if you want to get a block excution.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's perfectly legal to do it either way.

**BUT,** as Habib.OSU already said, there may be more things to consider, like dependencies between the entities you are going to save. There would several strategies to handle this.

**AND,** if you call `SaveChanges()` for each loop iteration this might cause **heavy performance issues**.